# Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi' & Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi-modular':

Tags: fedora

I am trying to configure a server with nginx and php but it turns out that when downloading or updating the metadata of the remi and remi-modular repository or simply when doing a dnf upgrade I get the error. Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi': y Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi-modular': and to top it off when installing MariaDB it throws me an error that says it needs gallery-4 so it doesn't let it update or nothing and throws the message.

```
Dropping packages with dependency conflicts: MariaDB-server x86_64 10.4.17-1.fc31 mariadb 17 M
  galley-4 x86_64 26.4.3-1.fc31.fc31 mariadb 13M
  galley-4 x86_64 26.4.4-1.fc31.fc31 mariadb 14M
  galley-4 x86_64 26.4.5-1.fc31 mariadb 14 M
  galley-4 x86_64 26.4.6-1.fc31 mariadb 14 M
```

please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWLUH.png)

I have already tried the commands to delete the history and everything but still nothing

```bash
sudo dnf clean all
sudo rm -r /var/cache/dnf
```

Comment: Message say the key is missing, check it is there. It is provided by the "remi-release" package, see https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/  (MariaDB is another issue, you should probably remove the F31 packages)